# How to determine the size of a text file from its content

Tags: c++, sizeof

Let's say a text file contains the following text:

```
1.11111111
2.22222222
3.33333333
4.44444444
5.55555555
```

What would be size of the file? And how can we determine it?

Hypothesis: [5*(10 bytes for ten characters on each line) + 5 null pointers at the end of each string] = 55 bytes.

But windows is showing me 3 extra bytes, total 58 bytes. Where do the 3 bytes come from?

EDIT:
NULL pointers take zero bytes. So, we have 8 extra bytes from somewhere.

More EDIT:
After some experimenting, each time we press ENTER we create 2 bytes. That's where the 8 bytes came from- from pressing ENTER 4 times. What are these bytes called in programming terms?

Comment: Open it in a hex editor? my guess is either `\n` and/or overhead

Comment: lines in files don't have null terminators, only strings do.

Comment: Another reason for a few extra bytes that you can't see would be a BOM. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: Lines don't end with "null pointers" and "null pointers" don't takes zero bytes to store...

Comment: @bames53, Troy: you are right. sizeof('\0') shows 1 byte. I thought each line would be considered one string, and thus ends with a null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`\n` and `\r` in end of each line except the last take 1 byte respectively.

Comment: So at the end of each line we have a \n (1 byte) and \r (1 byte), totalling 2 bytes, except the last one?

Comment: Yep. By the way in linux we have only `\n`, so I can bet you have windows :) You can read about control characters on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) and in [this book](http://books.google.ru/books?id=tU1ilZ71viwC&q=lafore+oop+in+c%2B%2B&dq=lafore+oop+in+c%2B%2B&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=90DJULP3N4mP4gSGyYCQBA&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA)

Comment: @user1478983 Yes, on Windows CRLF is usually used to end lines (a carriage return followed by a line feed, or `'\r'` followed by `'\n'`). Most other platforms just use a line feed.